# Dynamic SQL to backup DB and copy to different locations based on day

Tags: sql, sql-server, batch-file, dynamic-sql

We take daily backups of all DB's. There isn't enough space on the server so we copy it to a different server and also a different disk based on what day it is. i.e

```
Day 1 goes to \\SERVER2\E:\SqlBackups\Day1
Day 2 goes to \\SERVER2\E:\SqlBackups\Day2
Day 3 goes to \\SERVER2\E:\SqlBackups\Day3

Day 4 goes to \\SERVER2\H:\SqlBackups\Day4
Day 5 goes to \\SERVER2\H:\SqlBackups\Day5
```

etc

I want to use dynamic SQL and CMD but its not working, it either can't find the path or says the credentials are wrong even though the account has access to the shared drive

I've now decided to try getting the CMD to call a .bat file to do the copy but i'm not really familiar with how to do this.

I can obviously create a simple copy statement, but i do not know how to include the parameters etc

```
 DECLARE @SQL NVARCHAR(MAX)       
 DECLARE @Location nvarchar(200)
 DECLARE @Day   int
 SET @Day = DATEPART(dw, getdate())

 IF @Day in (1,2,3) SET @Location = 
 '\\Server2\BackUps\SqlBackups\'
 IF @Day in (4,5,6,7) SET @Location = 
 '\\Server\BackUps2\SqlBackups2\'

  SET @Location = @Location + 'Day'+ cast(@Day as nvarchar(1)) + '\'
  SET @Location = @Location + 'DB1.bak'


  SET @SQL = 'master..xp_cmdshell ''copy /Y 
  F:\SqlBackups\LatestToCopyToServer2\DB1.bak ' + @location + 
 ''''
  EXEC @SQL
```

The System cannot find the path specified.

if i just do a select the string looks good to me ...
     master..xp_cmdshell 'copy /Y F:\SqlBackups\LatestToCopyToServer2\DB1.bak 
     \Server2\BackUps\SqlBackups\Day5\DB1.bak'

To clarify i need assistance with the batch file and what to include :)

Comment: Could you add the final command the script is trying to execute and the error message you are getting?

Comment: the account that SQL server service is running under, does it have permissions to the share?  And second, if you print out `@SQL`, is the statement correct, and can you manually execute it successfully?  And third, you need to post exact error message received, else we will all be guessing what the problem is, and at that point, no one will bother to answer.

Comment: I would just set up two jobs.